# Firefox not rendering some Source Sans Pro characters

Tags: html, fonts, google-font-api

Using the Google Font "Source Sans Pro" I find that Firefox and Safari won't render the Czech characters 'Š' and 'č' properly (it seems to fall back to the next-choice font, which I've set to `serif` in the example below for clarity:

[image: Example rendering of HTML in Safari / Firefox]

However Chrome does a better job:

[image: Example rendering of HTML in Chrome]

so the font definitely includes these characters. Is this a bug in those browsers or a mistake in my HTML?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Test document</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400italic,700'
          rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Here is my Czech colleague's surname: Šimečková</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you see in Chrome as Š and č are not Source Sans Pro glyphs. They come from some fallback font, which happens to be much more similar to Source Sans Pro than the one you see in Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those accented characters are in the Latin Extended characters set. You should link to:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400italic,700&subset=latin-ext,latin
```

Comment: Thank you: thought I was missing something!